# Does CSS file have to be downloaded before the page is rendered?

Tags: html, css, web

I came across this question which contradicts with what I used to know :

Does style2.css have to be downloaded and parsed before Paragraph 1 is rendered on the page?

```
<head>
    <link href="style1.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <link href="style2.css" rel="stylesheet">
</body>
```

Answer: yes

I thought the html page is treated as a stream and every parsed element is displayed right away and the reason that some elements move around (or change style) while being displayed is that css files are downloaded after they are displayed on browser. Isn't that true ?

So if it takes 30 seconds to download each of the css files , during this time do we see the paragraphs ? or do we have to wait longer (30 or 60 seconds) to see them

Comment: You can try by making that stylesheet download really slow.

Comment: *"Does style2.css have to be downloaded and parsed before Paragraph 1 is rendered.."* -- In fact the css doesn't need to be downloaded at all, (if you don't want your content to be styled)!! If you do want your content to be styled, make sure that your css is downloaded before your content, to avoid the FOUC.

Comment: I expect that what'll happen is that the style on the page will update as the final stylesheet is rendered. This is what happens when you append stylesheets after the page is loaded via Javascript. If you do as Thilo suggests, you'll see the styles from style1.css until style2.css loads at which point the display will change.

Comment: can you provide your css for the P elements in both files

Comment: @Mayhem : It's supposed to be a theoretical question. The content of css doesn't matter. The size matters and how it affect the rendering of the page.

Comment: You cannot have a theoretical question about behaviour that is probably browser-engine specific.

Comment: I've been working on a PHP script that will explain this in further detail and allow to adjust / test how this behaviour works... If you dont use PHP or a server side, i would suggest one like xampp or bitnami.. hopefully no more than 15 mins.. Will create new answer for it.

Comment: Okay, Edited my answer and pasted my demo code in the bottom... Its a single file that does the css and html.. give it a try if you wish.. It shows how to use CSS for a progress loader of a page... this feels like a hack, but does show it of nicely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple approach to test this would be generate the CSS file using a server side language like PHP and place a sleep command in the CSS file..

This way it will pause the output of the file until the sleep command is complete and then finish the file download..

As for your question, Simply style1.css will be ready before the page loads (hence its in head)... Head will load/complete before anything on the body is rendered.

As the page loads, it will load with only style1.css styles applied... Once the page has rendered, it will start loading style2.css..Once that completes, it will apply those styles to your page. Causing a update/refresh on the page.

This is more or less the same as adding a CSS dynamically via ajax or something.

A page with NO CSS will still render, just it will render with the default styles for each element...

The only way this affect will change, is if for example you have a element shared between both styles.css and style1.css applies a display:none; or some other visible control method, which style2.css would show/reverse and all of a sudden the elements would be visible.

ALSO... why are you applying a css in the body / at the end of the document? Is there any desired effect you want?

**Generate Large CSS File Via PHP**

```
header( 'Content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8');
echo "/* FILE 1: Useless css comment */";
for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10000 ; $i++ ) {
    echo ".genEleme{$i} {width:{$i}px; height:{$i}px; background-color:#00aa00;} \r\n";
}
//Either use something like put contents or simply copy and paste from browser
// Seems this works out to 7mb give or take a little
```

Example output http://jsfiddle.net/hxdsskvs/1/

**PHP Script - Live Demo -Throttled Rate / Live Output**

```
<?php
// SCRIPT VARIABLES - These you can adjust 
$iDownloadRate = 1024; // Per Second

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
//    ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE IS YOUR OWN DOING - STAY ABOVE IN DOUBT
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// LETS SET A BUNCH OF HEADERS (Cache, Control, Chunked, Stay Awake)
    header('Cache-control: private');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Content-Encoding: chunked', true);
    header('Connection: Keep-Alive', true);
// PHP SETTINGS (Timeout, Buffering)
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 60);
    ini_set('output_buffering', false);
    ini_set('implicit_flush', true);

// SEND ANY EXISTING OUTPUT BUFFERS TO BROWSER (Empty & End) 
    while (@ob_end_flush());    

// ARRAY TO STORE OUR OUTPUT DATA (To access its size for the Content-Length)
    $aOutput = array();

// GENERATE CSS FILES else GENERATE HTML INDEX FILE
    if (isset($_REQUEST['cssfile'])) {
        header( 'Content-type: text/css; charset=utf-8');
        $sTmp  = "body,html{width:100%; height:100%;} \r\n";

        if ($_REQUEST['cssfile']==="header") {      // CSS FOR HEADER / PAGE LOADING STYLE
            $sTmp .= ".pLoading {font-size:2em; font-weight:bold; display:inline-block; margin:10px 0px 0px 20px; color:#000;} \r\n";
            $sTmp .= ".pBody1 {display:none;} \r\n";
            $sTmp .= ".pBody2 {display:none;} \r\n";
            $sTmp .= ".pComplete {display:none;} \r\n";
        }
        if ($_REQUEST['cssfile']==="body") {        // CSS FOR HEADER / PAGE LOADING STYLE
            $sTmp .= ".pLoading {font-size:2em; font-weight:bold; display:inline-block; margin:10px 0px 0px 40px; color:#333;} \r\n";
        }
        if ($_REQUEST['cssfile']==="body1") {       // CSS FOR HEADER / PAGE LOADING STYLE
            $sTmp .= ".pLoading {font-size:2em; font-weight:bold; display:inline-block; margin:10px 0px 0px 60px; color:#666;} \r\n";
            $sTmp .= ".pBody1 {display:block;} \r\n";
        }
        if ($_REQUEST['cssfile']==="body2") {       // CSS FOR HEADER / PAGE LOADING STYLE
            $sTmp .= ".pLoading {font-size:2em; font-weight:bold; display:inline-block; margin:10px 0px 0px 80px; color:#999;} \r\n";
            $sTmp .= ".pBody2 {display:block;} \r\n";
        }
        if ($_REQUEST['cssfile']==="footer") {
            $sTmp .= ".pLoading {display:none;} \r\n";
            $sTmp .= ".pComplete {font-size:2em; font-weight:bold; display:inline-block; margin:10px 0px 0px 0px; color:#aaa; text-align:center;} \r\n";
        }
        if ($_REQUEST['cssfile']==="footerdummy") {
            for( $i = 0 ; $i < 100; $i++ ) {
                $sTmp .= ".emljunk{$i} {width:{$i}px; height:{$i}px;} \r\n";
            }
            $sTmp .= ".pLoading {display:none;} \r\n";
            $sTmp .= ".pComplete {font-size:2em; font-weight:bold; display:inline-block; margin:10px 0px 0px 0px; color:#aaa; text-align:center;} \r\n";
        }

        $aOutput[] = $sTmp;
    } else {
        header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
        // HTML HEADER SECTION
        $sTmp = "";
        $sTmp .= "<html><head>";
            $sTmp .= "<link href='?cssfile=header' rel='stylesheet'>";
        $sTmp .= "</head>";
        $aOutput[] = $sTmp;


        // HTML BODY SECTION
        $sTmp = "";
        $sTmp .= "<body>";
            $sTmp .= "<p class='pLoading'>The page is currently loading, Please Wait</p>";
            $sTmp .= "<p class='pBody'>";
                for( $i = 0 ; $i < 5; $i++ ) {
                    $sTmp .= "<b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u>";
                    $sTmp .= "<b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u>";
                    $sTmp .= "<b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><br />";
                }
            $sTmp .= "</p>";
            $sTmp .= "<link href='?cssfile=body' rel='stylesheet'>";
            $sTmp .= "<p class='pBody1'>";
                for( $i = 0 ; $i < 5; $i++ ) {
                    $sTmp .= "<b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u>";
                    $sTmp .= "<b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u>";
                    $sTmp .= "<b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><br />";
                }
            $sTmp .= "</p>";
            $sTmp .= "<link href='?cssfile=body1' rel='stylesheet'>";
            $sTmp .= "<p class='pBody2'>";
                for( $i = 0 ; $i < 5; $i++ ) {
                    $sTmp .= "<b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u>";
                    $sTmp .= "<b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u>";
                    $sTmp .= "<b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><b>{$i}</b><i>{$i}</i><u>{$i}</u><br />";
                }
            $sTmp .= "</p>";
            $sTmp .= "<link href='?cssfile=body2' rel='stylesheet'>";
            $sTmp .= "<p class='pComplete'>The page has finished loading</p>";
            $sTmp .= "<link href='?cssfile=footer' rel='stylesheet'>";
            // If you remove this line for example, the footerdummy is joined in the same chunk as the above footer.... and they merge and wait for both to finish
            $sTmp .= "<p style='display:none;'>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>";

            $sTmp .= "<link href='?cssfile=footerdummy' rel='stylesheet'>";
        $sTmp .= "</body></html>";
        $aOutput[] = $sTmp;
    }




// COUNT LENGTH OF OUTPUT STRING / ARRAY
$sLen = 0;
for ($iL = 0 ; $iL < count($aOutput); $iL++ ) {
    $sLen += strlen($aOutput[$iL]);
}

// NOW SEND THE CONTENT LENGTH
header("Content-Length: ".$sLen);
$arr2 = str_split(implode("",$aOutput), $iDownloadRate / 1000);
foreach ($arr2 as $sChunk) {
    echo $sChunk;   // Echo a small chunk of the file.
    flush();        // Flush PHP buffers
    ob_flush();     // Send Output Buffers
    usleep(1000); // Create A Small Delay Per Chunk  |  1000000 =  second
}   

// TURN OUTPUT BUFFERING BACK ON - Normal HTML/PHP can follow from this point
ob_start();
```

With the above script, you can also do in such a way that you echo a css/link tag and then flush it.. That should ensure the css takes effect as soon as its sent. (Use the network view in your browser to debug as well)

Comment: I just wanted to study the effect. Thanks for the answer, but I tried it in chrome and the text doesn't show until the last CSS is downloaded.

Comment: And also, when I put it in the head, it is rendered with 0 delay (just like when I don't have any external CSS). But when I put it at the end of the file , it takes some time for the text to render.

Comment: Most likely your page is to small, You can look into output buffers and so on.. Eg, forcing the browser to display the content even though the page is still loading.. PHP is a great language for this level of control. If the browser output does not exceed the output buffer limit.. It will wait until its done before sending it to the browser.. Try adding 1024+ characters to the top of the document.. Something like a few comments or useless meta tags..

Comment: Does this work with just the example you have above? Or is this an extract from the problem project? As another possibility is you have other requests that are blocking the css file.. as most browsers limit how many externals they can get at once from a page.

Comment: No , it's the same very simple html, I added `link` tag to a 1kb external css file found randomly on internet. (do you know any VERY LARGE css file for testing ?)

Comment: If you can access PHP or do something similar, edited with code to generate a large css

Answer (score 0):

HTML parser reads line by line your code. If he founds any resource he attempts to get it's content. Only way to get content of external file is to download it to temporary directory.

Put some heavy js functions in head of page, put CSS file in the end and you will see that your elements will be "stock" for few moments and only when you download CSS file styles will be applied.

Is console's network tab you can see that all images, js, css, etc. files are downloaded. Always.